# How to set text to registered trademark symbol in fxml Label element

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

I'm just starting out with JavaFX and I'm trying to add a Label element in fxml file with text displaying the registered trademark symbol. (R inside a circle)

```
<Label styleClass="superscript" text="special_character" />
```

What would I put in place of `"special_character"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ISO-8859-1 codes. `<Label text="&#174;"/>`

Or the literal characters. `<Label text="®"/>`

For a searchable reference to the codes try
[ISO-8859-1 Characters Set for HTML](http://www.csgnetwork.com/htmlchrset.html)